# unable to install pihole giving error unable to initialize frontend: Dialog

Tags: 18.04, server, debconf

after i run this command :

```
$ curl -L install.pi-hole.net | bash
```

it gets stuck

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Installing packages
-------------------

..100%
```

but I do have debconf installed still says unable to intialize frontend

Comment: AFAIK that's not necessarily an issue - as it says, it will just use the Readline (text-based) interface instead. What is the actual issue you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to install both dialog boxes packages, which are mentioned in install script:

```
sudo apt-get install dialog whiptail
```

and then retry piHole installation.

Comment: It works but installation exits abruptly